# How to increment dates by exactly one month from a given date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I'm using Google Sheets and want to set a date in say `E:7`, then in Column B I want the first row to be the value `E:7` and then all the rows below that to be incremented by exactly one month from the one above. I know I can set `B:1` to `=E:7` however I can't figure out the best way to implement after that. Simply saying `B:1 + 30` doesn't work because not all months have 30 days.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you can use to **increment dates by exactly one month from a given date** is:

```
=ArrayFormula(EDATE(E7,SEQUENCE(14,1,1,1)))
```

[image: increment dates by exactly one month from a given date]

Functions used:

- [**`ArrayFormula`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en-GB)
- [**`EDATE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974?hl=en-GB)
- [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en-GB)

Comment: This looks great, and I think works exactly as I wan it to. I think it also helped me with another question I was going to have. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked out. `SEQUENCE` is a very nice, lately introduced function.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
In B1 type your start date.
Type in C1 the formula:
=EDATE(B1,1)
This would also do the trick and then drag it over the range you want and it will auto increment the month.

Comment: This worked well for me, I just had to use semicolon instead of comma.