# How to run a google sheets query against a dynamic range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

## Background

I have a spreadsheet that displays data internet consumption by users that looks like this

```
userid    feb1    feb2    feb3     .    feb29 
u1        100     34      23       .     4
u2        0       24      21             62
u3        300     25      5              1
u4        50      5       6      
.
.
un        23      52      3        .     42
```

I already wrote a [formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151290/how-to-sum-a-range-columns-from-another-google-sheet) that lists the daily consumption of each user like so:

```
date        daily consumption
feb1        14,971     
feb2        6,898       
feb3        10,666     
.
.

feb29        10,543
```

from the daily consumption I wrote a formula that gives me the highest amount consumed by a user on a daily basis so it looks like something like this

```
date        daily consumption    highest consumption
feb1        14,971               7,523
feb2        6,898                3,422
feb3        10,666               5,411
.
.

feb29        10,543              6,234
```

(this is what the query is where `March` is the sheet that contains the raw data

> query(transpose(QUERY(March!B3:C,"Select "&textjoin(",",true,ARRAYFORMULA("Max("& REGEXEXTRACT(address(1,column(March!B2:C),4,true,"March"),"March!(.*)\d")    &")")) &"",0)),"select Col2")

## Problem

What I'm trying to do now is find out on a daily basis the ID of the highest consumer like so:

```
date        daily consumption    highest consumption    highest consumer id
feb1        14,971               7,523                  4779221
feb2        6,898                3,422                  1047223  
feb3        10,666               5,411                  7505020
.
.

feb29        10,543              6,234                  2994922
```

I have two ways of getting the highest consumer Id manually:

### VLOOKUP method

ie

```
=vlookup(D2  ,{March!$I:$I,March!$B:$B},2,false)
=vlookup(D3  ,{March!$J:$J,March!$B:$B},2,false)
=vlookup(D4  ,{March!$K:$K,March!$B:$B},2,false)
..
```

### query method

ie

```
=query({March!$I:$I,March!$B:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 contains "&trunc(D2,5))
=query({March!$J:$J,March!$B:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 contains "&trunc(D3,5))
=query({March!$K:$K,March!$B:$B},"select Col2 where Col1 contains "&trunc(D4,5))
```

However I'm struggling with writing a formula that makes either work in a single line. What I'm trying to do is something along these lines:

for **vlookup** option:

> arrayformula(vlookup(D2:D3,indirect("March!$"& REGEXEXTRACT(address(1,column(March!$I:$J),4,true,"March"),"March!(.*)\d")  &":$" & REGEXEXTRACT(address(1,column(March!$I:$J),4,true,"March"),"March!(.*)\d")), indirect("March!$B:$B"),2,false))

for **query** option:

> arrayformula(query({indirect("March!$"& REGEXEXTRACT(address(1,column(March!$I:$J),4,true,"March"),"March!(.*)\d")  &":$" & REGEXEXTRACT(address(1,column(March!$I:$J),4,true,"March"),"March!(.*)\d")), indirect("March!$B:$B")},"select *"))

How do I make this work?

### why I need arrayformula rather than copy/pasting formulas across cells

the same sheet is very minimalist compared to the actual data I get from vendors. And this question is a about a single data analysis point I'm interested in - there are many more. Dragging formulas around will soon be cumbersome and not realistic. That's why I want to create arrayformulas instead.

## Sample sheet

note: the formulas will be a bit different on this sample sheet (same structure, different cell references)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OmVczb6KS8E6biDrtn8xSx1u1-urFjaFhY8lOVJdtGk/edit#gid=510221509

Comment: Most of March columns are empty, the highest consumption formula doesn't match the formula in the sample sheet.

Comment: I populated the rest of march's columns and fixed the formula

Comment: Filling the spreadsheet with so many `randbetween` was not nice (makes the spreadsheet very slow).

Comment: You seem hard to impress ruben

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=if( 
  sum(B3:B), 
  textjoin( ", ", true, filter($A3:$A, B3:B = max(B3:B)) ), 
  iferror(1/0) 
)
```

To do the same with an array formula, try this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  transpose( 
    iferror( 1 / ( 1 / 
      dmax( 
        B3:Z, 
        sequence(columns(B3:Z)), 
        transpose(iferror(column(B3:Z) / 0)) 
      ) 
    ) ) 
  ) 
)
```

To place these values in the 'Analysis' sheet, use this:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( hlookup( A2:A, { March!B2:2; March!B1:1 }, 2, false) ) )
```

Note that I had to replace the formula in A2 with a much simpler `transpose()`. The original formula is in B2.

See the ['Analysis'](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OmVczb6KS8E6biDrtn8xSx1u1-urFjaFhY8lOVJdtGk/edit#gid=510221509) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: cool, I updated my question with a more representative sample sheet btw. I'll take a look at your answer all the same

Comment: your answer doesn't work b/c I need a single line formula, yours has a formula for each column which isn't scalable:
`=if( sum(C3:C), textjoin( ", ", true, filter($A3:$A, C3:C = max(C3:C)) ), iferror(1/0) )` and `=if( sum(D3:D), textjoin( ", ", true, filter($A3:$A, D3:D = max(D3:D)) ), iferror(1/0) )` etc

Comment: I updated the sheet and have global permissions

Comment: The source data is the sheet "March".. I created a hand made column called "highest consumer id (static)".. I'm looking for a one line formula that we generate that column

Comment: why did you create a new "highest consumption" row in the "March" sheet.. instead of using the existing highest consumption column "ie Analysis!C1:C" in the Analysis sheet?

Comment: Your answer still relies on statically generating the data (using the formula `=if( 
  sum(B3:B), 
  textjoin..`, I need an answer that doesn't include any manual data generation

Comment: I edited the question and explained why I need arrayformulas. If the formula can be dragged across cells then there must be a way to do an array formula right?? My question is _how_

Comment: ".If the formula can be dragged across cells then there must be a way to do an array formula right??" Shortt answer :no.

Comment: interesting, this changes the whole way I thought `ArrayFormula` works!

Comment: `max()` works fine in an array formula, but it is an aggregating function so it will not get column-by-column results the way you seem to expect. Use `dmax()` instead. Edited the answer to include an array-enabled formula to get the column-by-column max value.